# Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting this error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types CustomerDetail and Customer.

Here is my `Customer` and `CustomerDetail` models

```
[Table("CUSTOMER")]
public class Customer
{
    [Required]
    [Column("CUSTOMER_ID")]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    [Column("FIRST_NAME")]
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    // other fields  

    public virtual CustomerDetail customerDetail {get; set;}
}

[Table("CUSTOMER_DETAIL")]
public class CustomerDetail
{
    [Required]
    [Column("CUSTOMER_DETAIL_ID")]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // other fields

    public virtual Customer Customer {get; set;} 
}
```

`Customer` to `CustomerDetail` has a 1:1 relation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that you have to specify a `ForeignKey` relation on the `Customer` property that maps to the key property exists on the entity.

```
[Table("CUSTOMER_DETAIL")]
public class CustomerDetail
{
    [Required]
    [Column("CUSTOMER_DETAIL_ID")]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // other fields

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Customer Customer {get; set;} 
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108160/entity-framework-code-first-setting-up-one-to-one-foreign-key-association-usin) refers to a different error, but has a similar goal to what you are trying to achieve.