# EF -- Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm having trouble working out what I am doing wrong here. I'm using asp.net Identity and I have created a new entity called `Person`. I updated the `ApplicationUser` Class to have a reference to the `Person`. I wanted to create a navigation property from `Person` to `User`. But when I execute the Update-Database I keep getting an error message

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'myapp.Models.ApplicationUser' and 'myapp.Models.DataModels.Person'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

```
public class Person 
{
    public Guid ID {get; set;}
    ...
    public virtual ApplicationUser user {get; set;}
}

public class ApplicationUser
{
    ...
    public Person person {get; set;}
}
```

In the code, I'm doing the following

```
ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser {...} 

Person person = new Person {....} 
user.person = person;
```

I'm also wondering whether I need to set anything for the Virtual property of `Person` such `person.user = user`;

I've tried to follow this [Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842363/unable-to-determine-the-principal-end-of-an-association-between-the-types) by doing the following on the virtual property:

```
public class Person 
{
    public Guid ID {get; set;}
    ...
    [ForeignKey("ID")]        
    public virtual ApplicationUser user {get; set;}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In `1:1` relation one end must be *principal* and second end must be *dependent*. *Principal* end is the one which will be inserted *first* and which can *exist without the dependent one*. *Dependent* end is the one which *must be inserted after the principal* because it *has foreign key* to the *principal*. Here you need to add `[Required]` attribute to one that is *principal* and remove `[ForeignKey("ID")]` from the model .

Also you have combined *lazy loading* (`Virtual` attribute) and *eager loading* features in your models.

Comment: Hi Amir, which one should I place the required attribute - should it be in the ApplicationUser.Person or Person.User ? I'm assuming it should be in ApplicationUser.Person but i tried it on Person.User and I'm able to execute Update-Database. But I would have thought that the ApplicationUser entity would be getting created first.

Comment: @user3836415 Which one is dependant? Add `[Required]` attribute for its navigation property.

Comment: I've tried to add the [required] annotation to each one and compiled it each time and I'm getting the same result.

Comment: I also find that  [Required] attr must be added to both the Id property and the reference property