# Implementing One to Zero-Or-One relationship in EF Code first by data annotation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

There's two entities in db, Cars and Car's image:

```
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class CarImage
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CarID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CarID")]
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public bool IsPrimaryImage { get; set; }
}
```

It's all good, works fine. Example: car with car is = 123 has 5 images, one of them has been marked as 'primary' (first uploaded image or manualy choosen by moderator).

Then i decide to optimize db model: remove `IsPrimaryImage`  and add `PrimaryImage` to Car as shown here:

```
public class CarImage
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CarID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CarID")]
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int? PrimaryImageID { get; set; }

    public virtual CarImage PrimaryImage { get; set; }
}
```

(Car *may* contain no images - that's why `int?`, not `int`)

Compile, run -- failed with error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to determine the principal end of an
>   association between the types 'MyApp.Domain.CarImage' and
>   'MyApp.Domain.Car'. The principal end of this association must be
>   explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data
>   annotations.

Found many similar topics on stackoverlow about this error:

- [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531671/what-does-principal-end-of-an-association-means-in-11-relationship-in-entity-fr), commons
- [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842363/unable-to-determine-the-principal-end-of-an-association-between-the-types?noredirect=1&lq=1), same error but 1:1 relationship, not my case
- [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701378/implementing-zero-or-one-to-zero-or-one-relationship-in-ef-code-first-by-fluent), looks like my case because about 1:0..1 but fluent API only.

Is it possible to fix error **with data annotation**? EF version is 6.

Comment: you don't use Fluent API ?

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh Sure, i preferer data annotation - it looks (for me) more clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found correct way:

```
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CarID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int? PrimaryImageID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CarImageID")]
    public virtual CarImage PrimaryImage { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class CarImage
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CarImageID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CarID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CarID")]
    [Required]
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

[image: sql]

P.S. <strike>Unfortunately, this not works for such IDs:</strike>

```
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class CarImage
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Update: If you specify your property as `ID` and ForeignKey as `Id` - this will cause an error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The ForeignKeyAttribute on property
>   'PrimaryImage' on type 'MyApp.Domain.Car' is not valid. The foreign
>   key name 'Id' was not found on the dependent type
>   'MyApp.Domain.CarImage'. The Name value should be a comma separated
>   list of foreign key property names.

So, this works also (case sensitive!):

```
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int? PrimaryImageID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ID")]
    public virtual CarImage PrimaryImage { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public class CarImage
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CarID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ID")]
    [Required]
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

[image: v2]

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, you don't need data annotations. You need to help EF figure out that a *Car* 'has' multiple *Images*, in stead of Car and Image being random entities that point to each other.

```
public class Car
{
  ...

  public virtual ICollection<CarImage> Images { get; set; } // <-- Adding this relation makes the problem go away :-)

  [ForeignKey("PrimaryImageID")]
  public virtual CarImage PrimaryImage { get; set; }
  public int? PrimaryImageID { get; set; }
}
```

Updated by A K: complete code is (works without `Required` on `virtual Car Car`, and it works with my styleguide for ID names)

```
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int? PrimaryImageID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PrimaryImageID")]
    public virtual CarImage PrimaryImage { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CarImage> Images { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class CarImage
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CarID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CarID")]
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

[image: sql management studio]

Comment: Like my own answer this works also. And, this looks more pretty that my version: it works with both primary keys (CarID -> ID). May I edit your answer before accepting (add sceenshot from sql management studio and complete sample of code)?

Comment: Please do!  Strictly speaking I implemented the model slightly different from what you originally proposed, your own answer is a more direct approach. I tend to setup the model to avoid true one<->one relationships in EF (and most other ORM's), because they are generally not handled very gracefully.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I've found the way to fix errors with prop `ID`, see update in my answer. I'll mark my solution as accepted for future visitors, your version less acceptable.