# How to configure One-to-One Relationship in Entity Framework, Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-one, table-relationships

First of all, I followed the example from this link: http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2011/06/02/entity-framework-4-1-one-to-one-mapping/ which seems solid, but when I try to create the scaffold, it crashes giving me the error that I have no navigation key.

Here's my code:

The class in charge:

```
 public class CodigoAgrupadorCuentas 
 {
    public CodigoAgrupadorCuentas()
    {
        CatalogoDeCuentas = new CatalogoDeCuentas();
    }

    public int CodigoAgrupadorCuentasID { get; set; }

    public string description { get; set; }

    public virtual CatalogoDeCuentas CatalogoDeCuentas { get; set; }

}
```

The dependant class:

```
public class CatalogoDeCuentas       
 {

    [ForeignKey("CodigoAgrupadorCuentasID")]
    public int CodigoAgrupadorCuentasID { get; set; }

    public string text { get; set; }

}
```

The DbContext class:

```
public class PolizasDBContext: DbContext
{
      public PolizasDBContext()
        : base("PolizasDBContext")
    { 

    }

      public DbSet<CatalogoDeCuentas> TablaCatalogoDeCuentas { get; set; }
      public DbSet<CodigoAgrupadorCuentas> TablaCodigoAgrupCuentas { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<CodigoAgrupadorCuentas>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.CatalogoDeCuentas)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }

}
```

And finally, here's the error image I get when I try to scaffold CatalogoDeCuentas:

[image: Scaffolding Error]

To summarize, What I want is to be able to Create a One-to-One Relationship where I can insert COdigoAgrupadorCuentas by itself, but not CatalogoDeCuentas.

I've been stuck at this simple problem for hours, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more reseach, I found the answer to my problems. Here's how the code ended:

The class in charge:

```
public class CodigoAgrupadorCuentas
{
    public int CodigoAgrupadorCuentasID { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set;}

    public virtual CatalogoDeCuentas CatalogoDeCuentas { get; set; }

}
```

Dependent class:

```
public class CatalogoDeCuentas  
{

    public int CodigoAgrupadorCuentasID { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

    public virtual CodigoAgrupadorCuentas CodigoAgrupadorCuentas { get; set; }

}
```

Context Class:

```
   public class PolizasDBContext: DbContext
{
      public PolizasDBContext()
        : base("PolizasDBContext")
    { 

    }

      public DbSet<CatalogoDeCuentas> TablaCatalogoDeCuentas { get; set; }
      public DbSet<CodigoAgrupadorCuentas> TablaCodigoAgrupCuentas { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<CodigoAgrupadorCuentas>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.CatalogoDeCuentas)
            .WithRequired(x => x.CodigoAgrupadorCuentas);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }

}
```

I got the answer from the following stack overflow question: [Entity Framework Code First : Setting up One-To-One foreign key association using Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108160/entity-framework-code-first-setting-up-one-to-one-foreign-key-association-usin)

Thanks a lot anyone that read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you need to specify the attribute `[ForeignKey("CodigoAgrupadorCuentasID")]`
above the `public virtual CuentasDelMes CuentasDelMes { get; set; }`

like this:

```
public class CatalogoDeCuentas       
{
   public int CodigoAgrupadorCuentasID { get; set; }
   public string text { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("CodigoAgrupadorCuentasID")]
   public virtual CuentasDelMes CuentasDelMes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jordy, I apologize, I made a mistake and forgot to remove CuentaDelMes from the code I posted, that's another relationship that the entity has and I already tested it earlier. 

I have updated my post removing that line of code.

My code is completely based off the end of the link that I provided, if you want to check the example out. I already had tried other methods before that too but there were always problems when trying to insert data to the table.

Comment: @JorgeDíaz the problem still there but now on the other class, i think look at the first two line in my answer