# EF - One to one relationships: ObjectContext instance has been disposed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-one

I am having some trouble with one to one relationships in EF.

Normally, I would define the key side of a (one to many) relationship, like so:

```
[ForeignKey("OrderId")]
public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
```

But when I do this with a one to one relationship, it fails to determine the principal end...

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'Retailer.ClientDB.EF.OrderOrigin' and
>   'Retailer.ClientDB.EF.Order'. The principal end of this
>   association must be explicitly configured using either the
>   relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Strangely, I don't get the error if I put the ForeignKeyAttribute on the id column, as I have done here with the relationship between Order and OrderOrigin.

```
[Table("ORDER_ORIGIN")]
public class OrderOrigin
{
    [Key, Column("uidorder"), ForeignKey("Order")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [Column("importfilename")]
    public string ImportFileName { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}


[Table("ORDERS")]
public class Order
{
    [Column("uidorder")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("uidstatus")]
    public int OrderStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual OrderOrigin OrderOrigin { get; set; }
}
```

But now, when I attempt to include() like this (which would normally work great)...

```
public List<ClientDB.EF.OrderOrigin> ListOrderOrigin_WithOrder(Common.Data.DBContext context)
{
   return context.EFDatabase.OrderOrigin.Include("Order").ToList();
}
```

...it fails to include Order and errors with the following when I try and access Order (after the context has been disposed of):

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used
>   for operations that require a connection.

Can anyone please advise how I can code one to one relationships in order to get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: The ObjectDisposedException has nothing to do with the fact that you are including the navigation property, you are passing the method a context that has been disposed.  This usually happens when you have a method that returns a context that is in  a `using` block.

Comment: @BenRobinson Actually, I am not. This method executes fine. Once it has run, I take the results, dispose of the context and do stuff with the returned data. This is when it errors. Normally, including include() would get the extra data I need and include it in the dataset. This is not happening.

Comment: It looks like it can't map your Order FK because there is no key field in the Order table called OrderId. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @CapTec The field is called uidorder and when I get orders directly (not via orderorigin) it works fine. The fault is not within the order definition itself, it is in the relationship.

Comment: @Beakie You may wish to read this [Shared primary keys](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10108574/1396796)

Comment: @CapTec Thanks for this. Problem solved with recommended chunk of fluent API instead of attributes. (Add as answer and I will mark it as such?)

Comment: @Beakie Whilst I'd get rep for posting an answer and you accepting it, I can't take the credit for the original posters work. Cheers though.