# Create one to one relationship optional on both sides in EF6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

Is there a way to map two entities to have one to one relationship optional on both sides using fluent API in Entity Framework 6?

**Code example**:

```
// Subscription (has FK OrderId)
this.HasOptional(t => t.Order)
    .WithOptionalDependent(t => t.Subscription)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.OrderId); // does not compile
```

**Context:** why would I do this? I work in an existing system where there are payment orders to buy subscriptions. When a order get paid a subscription is created and associated whit it, meaning subscription is optional to order. Also, there are other ways to create subscriptions, meaning order is optional to subscription.

Comment: In the past, it wasn't possible (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10108574/4812586)), but maybe you can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701378/implementing-zero-or-one-to-zero-or-one-relationship-in-ef-code-first-by-fluent)

Comment: There's a [lot to say about this.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21889367/861716)

Answer (score 1):

Usually in an one-to-one (or zero) relationship  both entities shares the same PK and, in the dependent one, the PK is also specified as FK. Check this [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s07.html) for more info about this. But if you entities not share the same PK, then you can't add a FK property in the dependent entity. If you do that, EF will throw an exception related with the multiplicity saying that it must be *.

About the relationship's configuration, there is only one way to configure an one-to-one relationship with both sides as optional, which it is what you currently have using Fluent Api. This way you can also use the [Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696571(v=vs.113).aspx) method  to rename the FK column that EF create by convention in the dependent table by the name that you already have in the `Subscription` table in your DB.

### Update

If you were not tied to an existing database, you could do something like this:

```
public class Subscription
{
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }

    public int? OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }

    public virtual Subscription Subscription { get; set; }
}
```

And the configuration would be this:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Subscription>()
            .HasOptional(s => s.Order)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(s=>s.OrderId);

 modelBuilder.Entity<>(Order)
            .HasOptional(s => s.Subscription)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(s=>s.SubscriptionId);
```

This way you can work with the `OrderId`FK  (and `SubscriptionId` too) like it was a one-to-one relationship. The problem here is you have to set and save both associations separately.

Comment: Using `Map` I am not allowed to define a property OrderId to handle the FK, so I will have to change a lot of code that uses `subscription.OrderId` in linq queries. Is there a workaround for it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you have an one to one relationship? It would be helpful if I could see the diagram of both tables,

Comment: quoting myself: "Context: why would I do this? I work in an existing system where there are payment orders to buy subscriptions. When a order get paid a subscription is created and associated whit it, meaning subscription is optional to order. Also, there are other ways to create subscriptions, meaning order is optional to subscription"

Comment: And business defined: one subscription for one order (if any), one order after payment, generates one subscription.

Comment: The ER is like this: `[Subscription] 0..1 ----- 0..1 [Order]`

Comment: If you really have an one-to-one relationship, in this case it is not possible specify a FK in the dependent entity. There are other ways to accomplish what you want but the problem is  you are tied to a scheme that already have in BD.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your help. Unfortunately I cannot accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this code in the database context class

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Subscription>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Order)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("SubscriptionId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Subscription)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("OrderId"));

    }
```

My test models are as follows

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Subscription Subscription { get; set; }
}
public class Subscription
{
    [Key]
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit:**
I did a reverse engineering to database trying to reach the required code structure by using double 1 to many relation to work like you want. The generated code is like the following. However, It is bad idea to do so.

```
public partial class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        this.Subscriptions = new List<Subscription>();
    }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subscription Subscription { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
public partial class Subscription
{
    public Subscription()
    {
        this.Orders = new List<Order>();
    }

    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
public class OrderMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.OrderId);

        // Properties
        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Orders");
        this.Property(t => t.OrderId).HasColumnName("OrderId");
        this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Description");
        this.Property(t => t.SubscriptionId).HasColumnName("SubscriptionId");

        // Relationships
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Subscription)
            .WithMany(t => t.Orders)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.SubscriptionId);

    }
}
public class SubscriptionMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Subscription>
{
    public SubscriptionMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.SubscriptionId);

        // Properties
        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Subscriptions");
        this.Property(t => t.SubscriptionId).HasColumnName("SubscriptionId");
        this.Property(t => t.OrderId).HasColumnName("OrderId");

        // Relationships
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Order)
            .WithMany(t => t.Subscriptions)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.OrderId);

    }
}
public partial class EFOrdersContextContext : DbContext
{
    static EFOrdersContextContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<EFOrdersContextContext>(null);
    }

    public EFOrdersContextContext()
        : base("Name=EFOrdersContextContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SubscriptionMap());
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work, entity framework complains: Subscription_Order_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Subscription_Order_Source' in relationship 'Subscription_Order'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Comment: It works only if you hide `OrderId` pk, something I cant. Anyway, thanks for your help.