# Multiple one to many relationships with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4.1, entity-relationship

I am using EntityFramework 4.1.

I have the following model:

```
public class User 
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Username { get; set; } 
   public string Password { get; set; }

   public virtual User Creator { get; set; }
   public virtual User LastEditor { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to generate my database I got this error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'User' and 'User'. The principal end of this association must be
>   explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data
>   annotations.

But I also have this class:

```
public class Course 
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; } 

   public virtual User Creator { get; set; }
   public virtual User LastEditor { get; set; }
}
```

And it works ok, I have these foreign keys generated:

```
Creator_Id
LastEditor_Id
```

Do I have anything to add in my User model to make it works?

Comment: Take a look at this question and see if it leads you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531671/what-does-principal-end-of-an-association-means-in-11-relationship-in-entity-fr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EF tries - by convention - to create a one-to-one relationship between `User.Creator` and `User.LastEditor` because they both refer to the `User` class where they are themselves located in. That's not the case for the `Course` class. For `Course.Creator` and `Course.LastEditor` EF creates two one-to-many relationships to the `User`. To achieve the same for the properties in `User` you will have to configure the relationships with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(u => u.Creator)     // or HasRequired
    .WithMany();

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(u => u.LastEditor)  // or HasRequired
    .WithMany();
```