# EF migrations exception: A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I've looked through existing questions surrounding this exception on SO but none seem to apply to my circumstances.

> ***A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'SchemaDictionaryId'.***

I am getting this exception when executing `Update-Database` in Package Manager Console.

My seed method is as follows:

```
protected override void Seed(DataEntry.App_Data.DataEntryDataContext context)
{
    context.Schemas.AddOrUpdate(s => s.SchemaId, _generateSchemaData());
    context.SaveChanges();
}

private Schema[] _generateSchemaData()
{
    List<Schema> schemas = new List<Schema>();
    // Loop removed for simplicity
    schemas.Add(new Schema
    {
        // various property assignments
        SchemaDictionary = new SchemaDictionary
        {
            // various property assignments
        }
    });
    return schemas.ToArray();
}
```

My DbContext subclass contains the following fluent API definitions (trimmed for relevance):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Schema>()
    .HasKey(s => s.SchemaId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Schema>()
    .Property(s => s.SchemaId)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
    .IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<SchemaDictionary>()
    .HasKey(sd => sd.SchemaDictionaryId);

modelBuilder.Entity<SchemaDictionary>()
    .Property(s => s.SchemaDictionaryId)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
    .IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<SchemaDictionary>()
    .HasRequired(sd => sd.Schema)
    .WithOptional(s => s.SchemaDictionary);
```

And finally the POCOs in question:

```
public class Schema
{
    public Guid SchemaId { get; set; }

    public Nullable<Guid> SchemaDictionaryId { get; set; }
    public virtual SchemaDictionary SchemaDictionary { get; set; }

    // various other properties
}

public class SchemaDictionary
{
    public Guid SchemaDictionaryId { get; set; }

    public Nullable<Guid> SchemaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Schema Schema { get; set; }

   // various other properties
}
```

The relationship between `Schema` and `SchemaDictionary` is meant to be of type **one to zero-or-one**...

- `Schema` object will have zero or one `SchemaDictionary`
- `SchemaDictionary` will always have a single `Schema`.

My understanding of the problem is that it cannot uphold the FK constraint because EF isn't aware of the `GUID` foreign key. How do I insert seed data when there is such a dependent relationship defined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SchemaDictionary>()
    .HasRequired(sd => sd.Schema)
    .WithOptional(s => s.SchemaDictionary);
```

You are [Configuring a Required-to-Optional Relationship (One-to–Zero-or-One)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx). You are specifying that the `SchemaDictionary` is the dependent and the `Schema` is the principal

When you have a one-to-one relationship in Entity Framework, the PK in the dependent must also be a FK to the principal. But you have specified that it should be database generated. The column cannot be both a FK and an IDENTITY so you get the error message. You should remove the `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)` from the `SchemaDictionaryId` property

As an aside some of your code is unnecessary

1. `HasKey` because EF will assume `SchemaId` and `SchemaDictionaryID` are keys by naming convention
2. `IsRequired()` on fields that are not nullable

References:

[When mapping, which is end is the principal?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19580798/150342)

[What does principal end mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6532401/150342)

Comment: Thanks, with a bit of tweaking of my seed method and the change you mentioned above this seems to have resolved it!