# codefirst one to one relationship

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using codefirst EF in asp.net application webforms. I have to class:

```
public class Product
{

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }        
    public virtual Picture Pic{ get; set; }

}

public class Picture
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key]
    public int PictureID { get; set; }


    public String Path { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int? ProductID { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

the relation between these classes is one-to-one. I set ForeignKey attribute but when I run Update-database I received "Multiplicity is not valid in Role.  Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'." 
can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

> [What does principal end of an association means in 1:1 relationship in Entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531671/what-does-principal-end-of-an-association-means-in-11-relationship-in-entity-fr#answer-6532401)

The one-to-one relation that EntityFramework can deal with is a relation between two primary keys (no Foreign Key exists), where one entity is the Principal and the other is the Dependent. The Dependent is the one that will refer to the Princial entity Id as its primary key. Means the primary key of the Dependent will be also its Foreign Key.

In your case the Product will be the Principal, and the Picture will be the Dependent. So, the PictureID for a Product with ID (5) is also (5).

This way your classes should look like the following:

```
[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{
    [Key, ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public virtual Picture Pic { get; set; }
}

[Table("Picture")]
public class Picture
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key, ForeignKey("Product")]    // Key, and Foreign Key the refers to ProductID
    public int PictureID { get; set; }

    public String Path { get; set; }

 // public int? ProductID { get; set; } // No foreign key, and ProductID can be accessed through the Product object below

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

and your database should look like:

[image: One-to-one relationship]