# Ef code first difference between principle and dependent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have these entities:

```
 public class StudentBag
 {
    public int BagIdentifier { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
 }

 public class Student
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public StudentBag StudentBag{get;set;}

 }
```

I want  to configure a one to one relationship. my question is if there is a difference between:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StudentBag>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.Student)
            .WithRequiredDependent(t=>t.StudentBag);

        modelBuilder.Entity<StudentBag>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.Student)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.StudentBag);
```

and I will appreciate if someone will explain what it is mean principle and dependent...

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531671/what-does-principal-end-of-an-association-means-in-11-relationship-in-entity-fr

Comment: I looked it talk about one to one or zero relationship no? "Principal end is the one which will be inserted first and which can exist without the dependent one" so I dont understand why in one to one I need it? In my example student can't exist without studendBag...

Comment: But entity framework still needs to put principal id into dependents foreign key column. Main difference between them, is that dependent has column with foreign key in it.

Comment: 1 to 1 is an anomaly. Both objets must be created together, updated together and deleted together. What's the point for this relation? What is your use case? Perhaps you need to use `ComplexObject`.

Answer (score 7):

It's pretty simple, the class that has the navigation property to the foreign class is the Principal.

When the **required class has the reference** to the main class you should use:
*WithRequiredPrincipal()*

When the **required class is referenced** by the main class you should use: 
*WithRequiredDependent()*

Eg. That way the two maps below are the same.

```
    //modelBuilder.Entity<>(Student)
        //.HasRequired(t => t.StudentBag)
        //.WithRequiredDependent();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.StudentBag)
        .WithRequiredDependent();

    modelBuilder.Entity<StudentBag>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.Student)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal();
```