# Problem with Inserting new row with EF in 1...0,1 Relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have two tables, Person and Employee and i have newly created `1 .. 0,1` relationship between them respectively. PersonId in Person table had defined identity 1. EmployeeId in Employee table doesnt have identity defined.

[image]

When i insert new row into Person table with SQL Studio everything works fine, however when i try to insert data with Entity Framework i get error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Person'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

PersonId is not explicitly defined and is `0` in time of saving.

Note that inserting new person row is working fine without relationship with employee.

Am I missing something obvious or my approach is completly wrong? Googling sadly didnt helped at all.

> EDIT: I have found solution, but i will add entity code for people
>   facing same problem.

Person entity:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
```

Employee Entity:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    ...
    public Data.Dal.Person Person { get; set; }
```

Relationship defined in context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
   .HasRequired(s => s.Person)
   .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.Employee);
```

Comment: Can you put your entities as well? I mean how your entity look like in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I am using Code First approach for generating Data Object Model.
EF created this relationship as:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
        .HasRequired(s => s.Person)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.Employee);
```

By EF definition Employee is main refereced class, which is wrong. I changed referenced class to Person and everything works fine so far.

Correct relationship:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
        .HasRequired(s => s.Person)
        .WithRequiredDependent(ad => ad.Employee);
```

More about having referece and being reference in answer: [Ef code first diference between principle and dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053263/ef-code-first-diference-between-principle-and-dependent)

Answer (score 0):

Do you you auto increment on your Id column ? Defined in your SQL database. 
If it is the case then try to decorate the corresponding property of your entity with 
DatabaseGenerated.Identity attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve your problem with SQL Server,make relationship with employee in your SQL server and try inserting new person again.