# How to announce the principal end of an 1:1 association in Entity framework using data annotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design

How do I announce the principal end of a 1:1 association in Entity framework using data annotations that are not Primary keys?

```
public class Event
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    public DateTime Stop { get { return Start.Add(Duration); } }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Guid? ScheduleStartID { get; set; }
    public Guid? ScheduleCalculatedID { get; set; }
    public Guid? SchedAltAddID { get; set; }
    public Guid? SchedAltRemoveID { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("StartEvent")]
    public virtual Schedule ScheduleStart { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("CalculatedEvents")]
    public virtual Schedule ScheduleCalculated { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("AddEvent")]
    public virtual ScheduleAlteration SchedAltAdd { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("RemoveEvent")]
    public virtual ScheduleAlteration SchedAltRemove { get; set; }
}


public class ScheduleAlteration
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid? AddEventID { get; set; }
    public Guid? RemoveEventID { get; set; }
    public Guid ScheduleID { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("SchedAltAdd")]
    public virtual Event AddEvent { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("SchedAltRemove")]
    public virtual Event  RemoveEvent { get; set; }
    public virtual Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
}
```

I get an error
**Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'MLNSC.Models.JobEvent' and 'MLNSC.Models.ScheduleAlteration'**

How do I specify that the Event is the principle object?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531671/what-does-principal-end-of-an-association-means-in-11-relationship-in-entity-fr) but not in the selected answer - that didn't work for me.  The second answer suggested using the [required] data annotation.

```
[required, InverseProperty("SchedAltAdd")]
public virtual Event AddEvent { get; set; }
```

I upvoted both the question & the answer that worked for me.