# Base Entity with self relation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

i have a base Entity Class like this :

```
 public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
    [Column("ID")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType("bigint")]
    public long id { get; set; }

    public virtual User createdBy { get; set; }

    public virtual User updatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime updatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

and a User Class for example like this :

```
public class User:BaseEntity
{
    public string userName { get; set; }


}
```

but the EF give me an error when i want add record to the user table . 
the error is this :

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'MvcPractice.Models.User' and 'MvcPractice.Models.User'. The
>   principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using
>   either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Comment: Are you missing a [foreign key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/gg193958.aspx)

Comment: i have to add foreign key in BaseEntity class like this ? 
[ForiegnKey]
public virtual User createdBy { get; set; }

Comment: [OnModelCreating](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206410/How-to-Configure-a-Self-Referencing-Entity-in-Code) add in the self references

Comment: i get this now : Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

Comment: not sure, post a new question, maybe [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations) adapted to a [one to many](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/using-self-referencing-tables)

Comment: You are missing a foreign key. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531671/what-does-principal-end-of-an-association-means-in-11-relationship-in-entity-fr).

Comment: using foreig key on wich field ? remember that base entity may be use in another model