# Entity Framework 1-to-1 relationship with ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, asp.net-boilerplate

How to set 1:1 relationship with the below-mentioned models when we use [ASP.NET Boilerplate](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/)? Thanks in advance.

**Note 1:** I have seen [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531671/what-does-principal-end-of-an-association-means-in-11-relationship-in-entity-fr) about the EF 1-to-1 relationship. But unfortunately, I don't know how to set it with ASP.NET Boilerplate because PK is automatically set by ABP. In my scenario, both tables have `int` PK.

**Note 2:** Here, the `Property` and `Address` models have 1:1 relationship.

**`Property` model**:

```
[Table("IpProperties")]
public class Property : FullAuditedEntity
{
    public virtual bool Vacant { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

**`Address` model**:

```
[Table("IpAddresses")]
public class Address : FullAuditedEntity
{ 
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(MaxLength)]
    public virtual string StreetNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Property Property { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relationship mapping should be done in the `OnModelCreating` method of your DbContext. Your DbContext class will be in the EntityFramework project under the EntityFramework folder.

You can use something like the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Property>().HasRequired(e => e.Address).WithOptional(e => e.Property);
}
```

If the `Property` property of the `Address` should not be null, the `.WithOptional()` method can be replaced with `WithRequiredDependent()` or `WithRequiredPrincipal()`, depending on the use case.

**Another Solution :**

**[ABP forum - REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY ISSUE - ONE TO ONE RELATIONSHIP](http://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=581&p=1902#p1902)**

Comment: Thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 0):

You will not find an HasOptional equivalent method in EF7. By convention if your FK property is nullable, you navigation property will be treated as optional

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Document)
                .WithOne(i => i.CancelNote)
                .HasForeignKey<Document>(b => b.CancelNoteForeignKey);
```

About your second question,EF Core (EF7) doesn't support Lazy Loading. In this link you will find the options you have now to load related entities

PS: please use your own entity names.