# Unable to map one to one in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm having trouble mapping a one to one relationship in EF 6.  My classes are:

```
public class Membership
{
     [Key]
     public decimal Id { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("Id")]
     public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
     [Key]
     public decimal Id { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("Id")]
     public virtual Membership Membership { get; set; }

}
```

I am getting the exception:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'User' and 'Membership'. The principal end of this association
>   must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API
>   or data annotations.

I think my issue is both tables has the same key value and do not store the key of the other.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the tutorial yet? [Configure One-to-Zero-or-One Relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Also why use `decimal` for an id column, int or long would be a better choice.

Comment: You can't have a true 1-1 relationship between tables.  One side must be optional or you'd never be able to add a row since each side requires that the other exists.

Comment: Thanks Igor.  The tutorial helped.  I use decimal because the DB2 driver doesn't seem to be able to map DECIMAL[13,0] to long.

Comment: @DanZ glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
public class Membership
{
 [Key]
 public decimal Id { get; set; }

 [ForeignKey("User")]
 public decimal UserId {get;set;}
 public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
 [Key]
 public decimal Id { get; set; }

 [ForeignKey("Membership ")]
 public decimal MemberShipId {get;set;}
 public virtual Membership Membership { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should [refer to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531671/what-does-principal-end-of-an-association-means-in-11-relationship-in-entity-fr) per ladislav, I'll put the contents here as well though.

> In one-to-one relation one end must be principal and second end must
>   be dependent. Principal end is the one which will be inserted first
>   and which can exist without the dependent one. Dependent end is the
>   one which must be inserted after the principal because it has foreign
>   key to the principal.
>
> In case of entity framework FK in dependent must also be its PK so in
>   your case you should use:

```
public class Boo
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Foo")]
    public string BooId{get;set;}
    public Foo Foo{get;set;}
}
```

Or using fluent mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
            .HasOptional(f => f.Boo)
            .WithRequired(s => s.Foo);
```