# How to solve error " The foreign key name was not found on the dependent type "

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

I have an application where I have created a login with the help of IDENTITY:

In the userTable I have created some custom properties and among these I have a property called "orgId" that lets me know which organization the user belongs to.

I created the organization Table in sql-managment studio and so far it is all good.

The orgId is a reference to the organization table (images below) and I can't figure out how to make this property a forein key on the user table.

Every time i Run the application i Get:

> The foreign key name 'OrganizationId' was not found on the dependent
>   type

My code:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("OrganizationId")]
    public Organizations OrgId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Organizations> Organizations { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here

        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FirstName", this.FirstName));

        return userIdentity;

    }
}
```

organizationClass:

```
public class Organizations
{
    public long OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

images:

[image]

[image]

Before posting this i tried a few things and amoing them was deleting all the identity generated tables but it did not work and now I get the error above which doesn't let me create anything.

I am fairly new to identity and have probably done something wrong.

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

after @Adil Mammadov answer which is extremly helpful I keep getting other errors.

my current error:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: One or more validation errors were detected
>   during model generation:
>   ApplicationUser_Organization_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in
>   Role 'ApplicationUser_Organization_Source' in relationship
>   'ApplicationUser_Organization'. Because the Dependent Role properties
>   are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the
>   Dependent Role must be '*'.

aslo i thought it would be good to point out the following:
in my startup.cs I have this:

public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            createRolesandUsers();
        }

```
    private void createRolesandUsers()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        var roleManager = new RoleManager<ApplicationRole>(new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

        // In Startup iam creating first Admin Role and creating a default Admin User    
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists(OverWatchRoles.SuperDeveloper.ToString()))
        {

            // first we create Admin rool   
            var role = new ApplicationRole();
            role.Name = "SuperDeveloper";

            roleManager.Create(role);

            //Here we create a Admin super user who will maintain the website                  

            var user = new ApplicationUser();
            user.UserName = "UserName";
            user.Email = "myname@myemail.com";
            user.FirstName = "Me";
            user.LastName = "Info";
            user.OrgId = 0;

            string userPWD = "123MyPassWord!'#";

            var chkUser = UserManager.Create(user, userPWD);

            //Add default User to Role Admin   
            if (chkUser.Succeeded)
            {
                var result1 = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, OverWatchRoles.SuperDeveloper.ToString());
            }
        }

        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Developer"))
        {
            var role = new ApplicationRole();
            role.Name = "Developer";
            roleManager.Create(role);

        }

        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("SuperAdministrator"))
        {
            var role = new ApplicationRole();
            role.Name = "SuperAdministrator";
            roleManager.Create(role);

        }

        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Administrator"))
        {
            var role = new ApplicationRole();
            role.Name = "Administrator";
            roleManager.Create(role);

        }

        // creating Creating Employee role    
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Employee"))
        {
            var role = new ApplicationRole();
            role.Name = "Employee";
            roleManager.Create(role);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can one Application user have multiple Organizations?

Comment: No, just one, if he is in two organizations the this would be a new post in the db. Edit: the scenario where the use would belong to multiple organizations is nonexistant so far.

Comment: Then why you have added `public virtual ICollection<Organizations> Organizations { get; set; }` to `ApplicationUser`?

Comment: I'll be honest, I do not quite understand how identity would make this a forein key and when browsing other questions i found simillar answers containg that and I'm experimenting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your models are not correct. You do not have `OrganizationId` in your `ApplicationUser` model, but you specify it as a foreign key. Also, you added two navigation properties for `Organization`:

```
// Yes, this is a navigation property
public Organizations OrgId { get; set; } 

// This is also navigation property
public virtual ICollection<Organizations> Organizations { get; set; }
```

Your model should look like something as below:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]    
    public long OrgId { get; set; }

    // Indicates that OrgId is foreign key for Organization navigation property
    [ForeignKey("OrgId")] 
    public virtual Organizations Organization { get; set; }

    ....
}   

public class Organizations
{
    [Key]
    public long OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Also consider changing name of `Organizations` class to `Organization`.

### Update.

This is *one-to-many* relationship. So, in `Organization` model navigation proeprty must be collection of `ApplicationUser`.

Comment: Thank you for a good answer! and thanks for guiding me to the link. 
However after applying the changes that you suggested I am getting: "Additional information: Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'OverWatch.Models.Organizations' and 'OverWatch.Models.ApplicationUser'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations."

Comment: @Ra3IDeN, which is principal in your case? Which of `ApplicaitonUser` and `Organization` is main entitiy?

Comment: The user belongs to an organization so i would say that the Organizations table is the main.

Comment: @Ra3IDeN, then add `[Required]` attribute to `public virtual Organizations Organization { get; set; }` at `ApplicationUser` class. If it works for you tell me, so I will update my answer. Have a look at to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12523397/1380428).

Comment: Please check my edits to the question. I get yet another error when setting the requiered attribute. Edit: check now please

Comment: @Ra3IDeN, I cannot see any changes in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122180/discussion-between-ra3iden-and-adil-mammadov).