# One to one relationship between entities not working in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the requirement of store data in a relationship between three tables using Entity Framework as:

**One to Many**
Employee --> Address
Employee --> Payroll
Employee --> Contact

This relationship indicates that for every Employee, there is Address, Payroll and Contact details. Technically, I'm trying to link EmployeeId as foregin key to all the three tables - Address, Payroll and Contact. Also, in Employee table, I'm storing the AddressId, PayrollId and ContactId as foreign keys which results in 1:1 relatopnship.
I'm trying to build the schema as follows:
Employee entity - Employee.cs

```
<code>
    [Table("tbl_Employee")]
    public class Employee: BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
        [MaxLength]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Guid ContactId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Guid PayrollId { get; set; }
        //FK References
        [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
        public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ContactId")]
        public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PayrollId")]
        public virtual Payroll Payroll { get; set; }
    }
</code>
```

Address Entity - Address.cs

```
<code>
[Table("tbl_Address")]
    public class Address: BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
        public string House { get; set; }
        public string Ward { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string PinCode { get; set; }
        public string AreaCode { get; set; }
        public string Landmark { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }

        //FK References
        [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }
</code>
```

Contact Entity - Contact.cs

```
<code>
[Table("tbl_Contact")]
    public class Contact: BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ContactId { get; set; }
        public string Landline { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string Fax { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }

        //FK References
        [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }
</code>
```

Payroll Entity - Payroll.cs

```
<code>
[Table("tbl_Payroll")]
    public class Payroll: BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid PayrollId { get; set; }
        public decimal BasicPay { get; set; }
        public decimal FlexiblePay { get; set; }
        public decimal PFContribution { get; set; }
        public decimal Allowances { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalPay { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }

        //FK References
        [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }
</code>
```

When I'm trying to use Package Manager Console to Add-Migration, it displays the following error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'NewEmployeeBuddy.Data.Entities.Employee.Employee' and
>   'NewEmployeeBuddy.Data.Entities.Employee.Address'. The principal end
>   of this association must be explicitly configured using either the
>   relationship fluent API or data annotations.

```
I googled about it and found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531671/what-does-principal-end-of-an-association-means-in-11-relationship-in-entity-fr  howeverstill getting the same error. Can someone please suggest any change in the code?
```

Answer (score 0):

In Address, Payroll, Contact try to remove the foreign keys and in primary keys use something like this [Key, ForeignKey("Employee")].

UPDATE:
For example Address Class should be:

```
Table("tbl_Address")]
public class Address: BaseEntity
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Employee")]
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
    public string House { get; set; }
    public string Ward { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PinCode { get; set; }
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }
    public string Landmark { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked for one Entity. I want EmployeeID to be the foreign key of all the three entites and have tried this: [Key, ForeignKey("Address, Contact, Payroll")] but not working. I also tried three ForeignKey attributes but it is not allowed :(

Comment: Yes I tried the same thing but the issue arises in case of Employee Scenario. The EmployeeId is Foregin key for three tables - Address, Contact, Payroll. So what I'm trying to achieve is the attribute over EmployeeId as [Key, ForeignKey("Address","Contact","Payroll")] which is not permissible.

Comment: In Employee class you only assign the key annotation to EmployeeId

Comment: What type of relationship do you want? In the title you mention 1 to many but in your description you say 1:1

Comment: Then you don't need EmployeeId to be foreign key to other tables. ;)