# Entity Framework - How to apply constraint to model properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, erd

I am using `Entity Framework 6.1.3` and have the two models as shown below. However, when I run migration I get the below error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'Example.Models.GiftVoucher' and
>   'Example.Models.Payment'. The principal end of this
>   association must be explicitly configured using either the
>   relationship fluent API or data annotations.

I have searched for it and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531671/what-does-principal-end-of-an-association-means-in-11-relationship-in-entity-fr). One of the solution was to use the `Required` attribute.

However, I don't know how I can do the following in Entity Framework:

- Rename GiftVoucherId and PaymentId in both models that are as foreign keys to `Purchase_Id` and `Redemption_Id`as shown in the image.
- Then do something equivalent in Entity Framework like this `CONSTRAINT fk-giftvoucher-table FOREIGN KEY (Purchase_Id) REFERENCES PAYMENT (PaymentId)`.

Payment Model

```
public class Payment { 

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public double Amount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int GiftVoucherId { get; set; }
    public GiftVoucher GiftVoucher { get; set; }

}
```

Gift Voucher Model

```
public class GiftVoucher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public double Amount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PaymentId { get; set; }
    public Payment Payment { get; set; }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't tend to use *one-to-one* relationships a lot... Unless i want to *Vertically Partition* for performance needs or there is an incessant [OCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder) need to separate the concerns.

***Note**: One-to-one relationship is technically not possible in SQL Server. It will always be *one-to-zero-or-one*. EF forms One-to-One relationships on entities not in DB.*

However, documentation is your friend

[Configuring a Relationship Where Both Ends Are Required (One-to-One)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Configuring%20a%20Relationship%20Where%20Both%20Ends%20Are%20Required%20(One-to-One))

> In most cases the Entity Framework can infer which type is the
>   dependent and which is the principal in a relationship. **However, when
>   both ends of the relationship are required** or both sides are optional
>   the **Entity Framework cannot identify the dependent and principal**. When
>   both ends of the relationship are required, use `WithRequiredPrincipal`
>   **or** `WithRequiredDependent` after the `HasRequired` method. 
>   ...

**Given the following**

```
public class GiftVoucher
{
    // your primary key
    public int GiftVoucherId { get; set; }
    public virtual Payment Payment { get; set; }

    // other properties
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}

public class Payment 
{ 
    // We need to share the same key
    public int GiftVoucherId { get; set; }
    public virtual GiftVoucher GiftVoucher { get; set; }

    // other properties
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

**We can Fluent API like this**

```
// Configure the primary key for the OfficeAssignment 
modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>() 
    .HasKey(t => t.GiftVoucherId); 

// we are essentially making GiftVoucher the principle in the DB
modelBuilder.Entity<GiftVoucher>() 
    .HasRequired(t => t.Payment) 
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.GiftVoucher);
```

So basically `HasRequired` is making `GiftVoucher` required and `WithRequiredPrincipal` is making `Payment` required.. In turn, EF will throw if the above is not satisfied

Comment: Would you please add the other properties I have in `Payment` and `GiftVoucher` models..It will make it more clear to me. Thank you

Comment: `Example.Models.Payment: : EntityType 'Payment' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Payments: EntityType: EntitySet 'Payments' is based on type 'Payment' that has no keys defined.` I am getting this error.

Comment: @MrNobody ahh sorry muddled it up, 2 secs

Comment: @MrNobody try that